# Double output in Twig nested loop

Tags: json, for-loop, twig

My data is derived from a `JSON` file of the following format:

```
{
  "primeNav": {
    "items": [
      {
        "text": "item",
        "url": "url1",
        "sub": [
          {
            "text": "subitem",
            "url": "url2",
          },
          {
            "text": "subitem2",
            "url": "url3",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I try and do:

```
<ul>
  {%- for item in primeNav.items -%}
    <li><a href={{ item.url }}>
      {{- item.text -}}
      {%- if item.sub -%}
        <ul>
          {%- for subItem in item.sub -%}
            <li><a href="{{ subItem.url }}">
              {{- subItem.text -}}
            </a></li>
          {%- endfor -%}
        </ul>
      {%- endif -%}
    </a></li>
  {%- endfor -%}
</ul>
```

The output I get is (sans the whitespace):

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="url1">item</a>
    <ul>
      <a href="url1"></a>
      <li>
        <a href="url"></a>
        <a href="url2">subitem</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="url"></a>
        <a href="url3">subitem2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

From some reason I can't quite get `<a href="url"></a>` is printed inside the second `ul` and each of it child `li`s in a way that doesn't seem to be consistent with my template.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you nested `<a>`? Is that even allowed? Did you got that html from browser dev tool? Maybe browser is trying to do something with your invalid nested `<a>`?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mean to nest the `<a>`s. That's most likely the issue